# VB.NET Connection string with Door access controller CHIYU BF Mini -W-E

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

Can anyone help about connection string to LAN device (Door access controller CHIYU BF Mini -W-E).

I need to make bidirectional connection to this device, so I can get data from and send data to the same device. When I will get data from the device, the idea is to put that data in some data Base and letter make some analysis.

In the opposite direction I will send command to the device.

Comment: "Connection strings" are only relevant in the context of OLE-DB, ODBC and SQL Server or any other specific platform or product that adopts the term (like Azure Storage). I'm unfamiliar with Chiyu door-locks - do they have an SDK that also uses the term "connection string" to configure a client to connect to their system?

Comment: Yes, they tell dhat have an SDK, but I can't find anywhere